# Display lists next to each other without float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display unordered lists next to each other but can't get it to work even when I use css rules to match the way they display.

Heres my code:

```
<ul class="outterList">
    <li>
       <span class="bigText">Main</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class="medText">Included</span>
       <ul class="innerList">
            <li>TestMessage - text</li>
            <li>bla - text</li>
            <li>asffadgsd - text</li>
            <li>iuygouhlubrsf - text</li>
            <li>New Test - text</li>
            <li>TestFileName - photo</li>
            <li>TestFileName2 - photo</li>
            <li>jvv - photo</li>
            <li>ujjjjjjjjjjj - photo</li>
            <li>MR. Bean - text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
.outterList{
    display: inline ;       
}

.innerList{
    display: block;
}
```

What Im trying to show is somthing like:

```
        List1(empty list)           List2

                                    *item1

                                    *item2
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.outterList{
    display: block;  
}

.outterList > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8qNj/4/

Comment: The OP is asking to display *lists* next to each other, and not the *items in the list*, as stated in the title, question, and layout.

Comment: The lists are next to each other without float. My fiddle shows exactly how the example given in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I misunderstood the question. I thought OP meant displaying top-level lists beside each other, instead of nested lists.

Comment: No problem @Zhihao, I forgive you this time. x)